# create roaming profile in windows 2008 server for ubuntu 12.04 client

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, xubuntu, user-profile

> i ve a windows 2008 Domain Controller, and i have created roaming profile that is working >>fine in windows environment..
>
> > > now i have joined Ubuntu 12.04 as a client to use likewise-open, but that roaming >>>>profile >is not working for Ubuntu PC.
> > >
> > > > > > how can i use roaming profile in Ubuntu PC as a client???? 
> > > > > >             ??????can anyone help me???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu does not support Roaming Profiles in the Microsoft sense.

While on Windows the C:\Users\username folder is "just a collection of files and folders," there are very specific registry files, System Folders (for things like certificates and encryption keys), file layouts and Access Control Lists that are required for it to "just work" on Windows. Linux just doesn't work that way.

If you're happy to just synchronize your Documents folder between Ubuntu machines then this baked-in with Ubuntu One. (Actually, Ubuntu One can sync more than the Documents folder, but it's a click frenzy setting it up.) If you'd like your whole /home/user folder synchronized, though, you'll have to do a little more work with rsync or Unison.

Comment: ok , thanx.. does roaming profile supports from Ubuntu server to ubuntu client???
if yes then how can i configure ???

Comment: @anp: I have not tried this specific guide, but this is a fairly recent guide that should do want you want to: http://linuxphilia.blogspot.com.au/2012/06/setting-up-network-based-centralized.html